# How to create a database in MySQL Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I've recently installed the official MySQL extension for Python. However, when connecting to the server it asks me to select the database, but I have not made a database yet.

I don't really know what to do here. So I tried to connect using my information without the database but received errors with the following code:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='ubuntulogin', password='ubuntupassword',
                          host='localhost')

cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("CREATE DATABASE database")

cursor.execute(query)

cursor.close()

cnx.close()
```

Please let me know any issues with my code or how to get MySQL information when I don't know mydatabase name.

Thanks

EDIT: My error message when running the code was:

```
File "/home/liam/sqltest.py", line 3, in <module>
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='ubuntulogin', password='ubuntupassword', host='localhost')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 162, in connect
return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 129, in __init__
self.connect(**kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 454, in connect
self._open_connection()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 417, in _open_connection
self._socket.open_connection()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 475, in open_connection
errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message in your question.

Comment: Sorry I'll do that now

Comment: @DYZ I've added the error message, sorry about not including it earlier

Comment: Looks like you haven't started the MySQL server or you do not have an account with the credentials 'ubuntulogin' and 'ubuntupassword'.

Comment: @DYZ How do I start the MySQL server. Are the credentials different to what I use to login to my actual server?

Comment: @DYZ I got it working since I thought that the MySQL server was pre-installed like it was in PHP, however, it is not. I've got it working and thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so it turns out that I am a complete idiot. I was under the impression that MySQL was pre-installed and running since I am used to PHP. However, I just installed it and use my code above and everything seems to be working.

Thanks to @DYZ for pointing out that it looked like I hadn't started the MySQL server and my credentials were incorrect (which turned out to be both true.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot something)

```
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE database;")
```

Comment: The OP has this line in their code. The semicolon at the end is optional.